# Can not get rule explicit-function-return-type to turn off in eslint for typescript linting

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I am using:
eslint v7.5.0 - running on command line for Angular files
typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin v3.7.0
typescript-eslint/parser v3.7.0.

I keep getting `warning  Missing return type on function` in spite of the rule disabled `'@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',`.

What am I doing wrong where this rule is not disabled?

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  extends: [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually regression with eslint and typescript. Bug report filed here https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2267